# How to define MapKey column name on Map<String, Embeddable>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Short version: 
 I'm trying to create an:

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<String, Item> items;
```

, where `Item` is `@Embeddable`, and be able to define the column name created in `Item` table for the map's key. Hibernate version: 5.0.12.Final

**Full explanation**: 
Following is a simplified example that reproduces my problem. 
My starting point is a `List` of `@Embeddable`.

```
@Entity
public class Root {
    @Id
    private Long code;   

    private String value;    

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Item> items;
}
@Embeddable
public class Item {
    private String keyValue;    
    private String otherValue;
}
```

with this mappings hibernate creates the following tables:

```
create table root (
    code int8 not null,
    value varchar(255),
    primary key (code)
);

create table root_items (
    root_code int8 not null,
    key_value varchar(255),
    other_value varchar(255)
);

alter table root_items 
    add constraint FK1o7au7f9ccr8144vyfgsr194v 
    foreign key (root_code) 
    references root;
```

So far so good. Next, I'm trying to convert the `List` to a `Map` and use `Item.keyValue` as the map's key:

```
@Entity
public class Root {
    @Id
    private Long code;

    private String value;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String, Item> items;
}
@Embeddable
public class Item {
    private String otherValue;
}
```

It works, but in `root_items` table the map's key column is always called `items_key` and I'm unable to find how to force this name to `key_value`.

I've tried the following alternatives:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "keyValue")
private Map<String, Item> items;


/* @MapKey doesn't work at all. 
    org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associated class not found: com.demo.Item
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder.bindKeyFromAssociationTable(MapBinder.java:116)
*/
@ElementCollection
@MapKey(name = "keyValue")
private Map<String, Item> items;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "code"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "keyValue")
private Map<String, Item> items;

@ElementCollection
@JoinColumn(name = "keyValue")
private Map<String, Item> items;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "code"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "keyValue")
@Column(name = "keyValue")
private Map<String, Item> items;
```

but the column name is always generated as `items_key`:

```
create table root_items (
    code int8 not null,
    other_value varchar(255),
    items_key varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (code, items_key)
);
```

I've also tried all the above combinations keeping `keyValue` in `Item` but then I only get and extra column:

```
create table root_items (
    code int8 not null,
    key_value varchar(255),
    other_value varchar(255),
    items_key varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (code, items_key)
);
```

Similar questions I've found but doesn't solve my problem:

- [@ElementCollection with Map<Entity, Embeddable> where Entity is a field of the Embeddable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974096/elementcollection-with-mapentity-embeddable-where-entity-is-a-field-of-the-e)
- [Key & value column name overrides when mapping java.util.Map with JPA annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138694/key-value-column-name-overrides-when-mapping-java-util-map-with-jpa-annotation)

Is there anyway to force the column name to some custom value?

**EDIT 1:**
I've found that if the map key is `@Embeddable` then I can achieve it.
But I don't think it's a valid solution to achieve this. I would like to keep the map key as `String`

```
@Entity
public class Root {
    @Id
    private Long code;

    private String value;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<ItemKey, Item> items;
}
@Embeddable
public class ItemKey {
    private String keyValue;
}
```

Is there anyway to force the column name to some custom value when the key is `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found it. It's as simple as that:

```
@Entity
public class Root {
    @Id
    private Long code;

    private String value;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "keyValue")
    private Map<String, Item> items;
}
```

I leave the answer in case it may help another one as lost as I. :P

Comment: It gives me an error: Repeated column in mapping for collection: com.example.Root.items column: key_value