# JPA map an Embeddable class which contains a Map<Entity, Embeddable>

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm writing a Java EE application using JPA and it needs to be internationalized.
To do so, I created a class called `MultilingualString` which associates a `Language` with a `String`
(and so extends `HashMap<Language, String>`) as followed :

```
/**
 * This class is mapped to the database thanks
 * to the Locale.toLanguageTag() method
 * and Locale.fromLanguageTag(String) constructor
 */
public class Language {
    public Locale locale;

    /* Getters, Setters ... */  
}

/**
 * NB : This class extends HashMap to override the put method
 * which needs to ignore putting null values instead of throwing
 * a NullPointerException
 */
public class MultilingualString extends HashMap<Language, String> {
    public Map<Language, String> getStrings() {
        return (this);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Now, say we have an `Entity` which has a different name depending on the `Language` :

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Entity {
    private Long id;
    private MultilingualString name;

    @Id
    public Long getId() { ... }

    @Transient
    public MultilingualString getName() { ... }

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "language_id")
    public Map<Language, String> getStrings() {
        return (this.name.getStrings());
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

This code produces the following database schema :

```
Language        :
    id          | bigint                        | NOT NULL  | primary key
    languageTag | character varying(255)        |           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Entity          :
    id          | bigint                        | NOT NULL  | primary key
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Entity_strings  :
    entity_id   | bigint                        |           | foreign key references Entity(id)
    language_id | bigint                        |           | foreign key references Language(id)
    string      | character varying(255)        |           |
```

Which is almost good.

The problem with this implementation is the repetition of the `@Transient` on the `MultilingualString` field
and `@ElementCollection @MapKeyJoinColumn` on the `getStrings()` method (which you have to re-write everytime
you need to map a `MultilingualString` in database BTW : at least 1 per entity class).
In my opinion, it makes the code ugly and harder to maintain.

The other thing is : it's the `Entity` which associates the `Language` to the `String` through the `Map`.
There should be a class which associates both of them : say a `LocalizedString` as I read
[here](http://hwellmann.blogspot.fr/2010/07/jpa-20-mapping-map.html)

So I would like `MultilingualString` to behave like a value type so
I don't need to repeat those multiple annotations mentionned above and implement a `LocalizedString`.

Here follows what I've come up with so far. It does NOT work, GlassFish won't start
with such a mapping, I always get a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` when EclipseLink see the `MultilingualString` mapping.

```
@Embeddable
public class LocalizedString {
    @ManyToOne
    private Language language;
    private String string;
}

@Embeddable
public class MultilingualString extends HashMap<Language, LocalizedString> {

    /**
     * Here I lost myself in all the available annotations
     * and tried thousands of permutation, but always the same exception
     * @MapKeyJoinColumn ?
     * @MapKeyClass ?
     * @CollectionTable ?
     * ...
     */
    @ElementCollection
    public Map<Language, LocalizedString> getStrings() {
        return (this);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Embedded
    private MultilingualString name;
}
```

So I would like, with this implementation, to get the same (or nearest possible) database mapping as written above.
Is that even possible ? I read that an `Embeddable` class should not contain another (collection of )`Embeddable` class, but here, it's the case for me.

I read several articles and blogs and didn't found so many situations like this one ("JPA Map with Entity key and Embeddable value")

Actually, I'm trying to do something similar to [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/MapKeyColumns#Example_of_a_map_key_join_column_relationship_annotation)
except that my map value is an `Embeddable` class.
I found [ONE similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754480/in-jpa-a-map-of-embeddable-values-that-have-an-embedded-entity-used-as-the-key)
(except that I would have wanted his `Root` class to be `Embeddable`) on StackOverflow, with an answer that I tested (no luck) but it was not "marked as the answer" and the question didn't have much success.

Comment: I don't think that Entity class should be modified to contain any information on i18n. You need to keep only keys in your entity, and depending on locale get localized message for it and pass through... As far as I can see you're persisting localization content to the database?

Comment: @Vach Yes I am, but I need to : the user is invited by a form to add some `Entity` instances and this form ask the user for the name is the languages available in database. Those names are not static. For static labels of course, I don't store them in the database, I have some properties files (messages_en, messages_fr, etc ...) but I can't use them for that purpose because I can't know what the strings will be.

Comment: Ok, I've had such experience and here's what I did. I had almost the same case as yours, user should enter localization information. At first I (just like you stored it with entities) that was horable. Then we kept separate entity for localization information, this entity kept necessary information to locate the specific entity and all the localization conserning to it. Target entities didnt know anything about their localization. Then we wrote an Aspect, this aspect took all those methods we were interested to return localized value and after execution injected localized content...

Comment: Thus user logging in with specific locale were getting exactly that localization information (or default english if none were available). We cached those aspect executions and everything worked very fine... My point here is that localization is a "CROSS CUTTING CONCERN" the typical task for AOP, and trying to implement it via OOP will only harm your performance and code readability... AOP is a really must to know technology for compilable languages like java, once you use it you will wonder how were you doing without it so far...

Comment: I can give you that aspect code if you need. And there is not only the Localization problem that you can solve that way, its security, transaction management, logging etc...

Comment: I'll check AOP then (I didn't know it until now), thanks for your comments.

Comment: Also I think @transient in entity classes is really bad approach, you should think of your entities as a data structure. I try to make my entities effectively immutable. Generally if you come up with an idea to use transient in entity then you might consider writing adapter class that uses composition and provide business logic to acheave required functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example of aspect that can handle localization of your entity(s) :

```
@Aspect
public class LocalizationAspect {

    @AfterReturning(
            pointcut = "@within(MyManager) && execution(MyEntity methodThatReturnsEntity(..))",
            returning = "entity"
    )
    public void localizeMyEntity(MyEntity entity) {
        localize(entity);
    }
}
```

With minor changes you can apply this for collections of returned entities...

localie() is using entity id to navigate and inject localization information into that entity before result is returned.